# Transaction is not active using OpenJPA

Tags: java, postgresql, servlets, jpa, openjpa

i have a frustrating problem with my servlet. This is very basic, i'm supposed to add a blog entry to my database table which has 3 columns (id, tittel(title), main(mainbody)). I can load from my database and display in my jsp file. However i can't persist the data to the database and i cant figure out why.

I use postgres as a database.

**This is my "saveBlog"-method:**

```
public void lagreBlogg(Blogg b){
           EntityManager em =      Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("kimsBlogg").createEntityManager();
            EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();

           try {
            transaction.begin();
            em.persist(b);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            transaction.rollback();

        } finally {
            em.close();
        }

    }

}
```

**This is my entity class:**

```
 @Entity
 @Table(schema = "blogg", name = "blogg")
 public class Blogg {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;
private String tittel;
private String main;


public Blogg() {

}

public Blogg(String tittel, String main){
    this.tittel= tittel;
    this.main = main;
}

public String getTittel() {
    return tittel;
}

public void setTittel(String tittel) {
    this.tittel = tittel;
}

public String getMain() {
    return main;
}

public void setMain(String main) {
    this.main = main;
}
}
```

**My persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">

<persistence-unit name="kimsBlogg">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl
    </provider>

    <class>no.kim.model.Blogg</class>




    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.logging.level" value="INFO" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="krheggen" />
        <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="supported" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

**This is the error i get:**

HTTP Status 500 - Can only perform operation while a transaction is active.

type Exception report

message Can only perform operation while a transaction is active.

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.openjpa.persistence.InvalidStateException: Can only perform operation while a transaction is active.
    org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.assertTransactionOperation(BrokerImpl.java:4732)
    org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.rollback(BrokerImpl.java:1543)
    org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.rollback(DelegatingBroker.java:940)
    org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.rollback(EntityManagerImpl.java:598)
    no.kim.helpers.BloggDAO.lagreBlogg(BloggDAO.java:37)
    no.kim.Controller.BloggServlet.doPost(BloggServlet.java:33)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

**StackTrace**

Caused by:  org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: ERROR: relation "blogg.openjpa_sequence_table" does not exist
  Position: 28 {prepstmnt 166406485 SELECT SEQUENCE_VALUE FROM blogg.OPENJPA_SEQUENCE_TABLE WHERE ID = ? FOR UPDATE} [code=0, state=42P01]
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.narrow(DBDictionary.java:5001)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.newStoreException(DBDictionary.java:4961)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:133)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:107)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:59)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractJDBCSeq.next(AbstractJDBCSeq.java:63)
    at org.apache.openjpa.util.ImplHelper.generateValue(ImplHelper.java:159)
    at org.apache.openjpa.util.ImplHelper.generateFieldValue(ImplHelper.java:143)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.assignField(JDBCStoreManager.java:774)
    at org.apache.openjpa.util.ApplicationIds.assign(ApplicationIds.java:492)
    at org.apache.openjpa.util.ApplicationIds.assign(ApplicationIds.java:468)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.assignObjectId(JDBCStoreManager.java:758)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingStoreManager.assignObjectId(DelegatingStoreManager.java:135)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.assignObjectId(StateManagerImpl.java:595)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.preFlush(StateManagerImpl.java:3051)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.PNewState.beforeFlush(PNewState.java:44)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.beforeFlush(StateManagerImpl.java:1072)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:2143)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flushSafe(BrokerImpl.java:2103)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.beforeCompletion(BrokerImpl.java:2021)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.LocalManagedRuntime.commit(LocalManagedRuntime.java:81)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.commit(BrokerImpl.java:1526)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.commit(DelegatingBroker.java:932)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.commit(EntityManagerImpl.java:569)

Comment: the problem is your " transaction.rollback();" in the catch method. please print out the exception. if commit fails with an exception the connection is not longer active

Comment: Added persistence.xml

Comment: about the title, it has nothing to do with Servlets, it should be something like "Transaction is not active using OpenJPA"

Comment: BloggDAO is provided(the method the error comes from). the line 37 is this line "catch (Exception e) {" in saveBlog-method

Comment: You should print (or log) the exception in the `catch ()` block, not just ignore it. It will most probably tell you the real reason of your problem.

Comment: You should tell OpenJPA to use native Postgres sequences, not the "homegrown" implementation using a sequence table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> relation "blogg.openjpa_sequence_table" does not exist

This seems to be straightforward, just create a sequence for the table `blogg`, more information [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-createsequence.html).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `" transaction.rollback();"` in the catch method. if commit fails with an exception the connection is not longer active.

Comment: why the downvote? this is the solution ...
If commit fails, it is rollbacked(auto)  and the transaction is inactive.

Comment: But the commit should work. Thats the problem, i dont know why it goes to rollback(). That is what i need a solution for

Comment: but what is the stacktrace of the exception? in the  catch (Exception e) {
            transaction.rollback(); ?

Comment: no because of the line " transaction.rollback();"  another excption occurs. this is the exception: "Can only perform operation while a transaction is active". But you don't print the exception from the line 
" transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {"  . please add a e.printStacktrace() instead of the transaction.rollback.

Comment: yes, this is the root cause. it occurs because of the annotation  @GeneratedValue. I don't know what you have to change but have a look at the documentation from openjpa. there is a description of this table  - http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/ref_guide_sequence.html

"Table: The name of the sequence number table to use. Defaults to OPENJPA_SEQUENCE_TABLE" (and please upvote my answer :-), because it is correct)

or have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874500/openjpa-1-sequence-table-not-being-created

Comment: It wasn't me that downvoted it, but i will give u an upvote :)